# Matching "in between" dataframe values in R

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm just a beginner in R (I use Python before to clean data), so let's go straight to the point.

Problem: I'm working on Latitude and Longitude values and I want to display where each of them lie in a given range (in another dataframe).

**Example**
Dataframe 1: df_longlat

***LAT_ LONG_***

14.57244 120.9822

Dataframe 2: df_grid

***Grid_ID lat1 lat2 long1 long2***

1000    14.57546  14.57097  120.9778   120.9827

**Expected Result:** (Since both Latitude and Longitude from the first dataframe is inside the range given in the second dataframe, Grid_ID = 1000 is reflected in the first dataframe.)

***Grid_ID LAT_ LONG_***

1000    14.57244 120.9822

**Solution Attempt:** I tried doing an ifelse for this dataframe, but it won't scan every individual entry. I need something that will scan all entries in dataframe1 so that they will get the grid ID in dataframe2.

```
Lat_Test <- ifelse(((df_longlat$LAT_ >= df_grid$lat2) & (df_longlat$LAT_ <= df_grid$lat1)),df_grid$grid_id, NA)
Lat_Test <- as.data.frame(Lat_Test)
Long_Test <- ifelse(((df_longlat$LONG_ >= df_grid$long1) & (df_longlat$LONG_ <= df_grid$long2)),df_grid$grid_id, NA)
Long_Test <- as.data.frame((Long_Test))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `fuzzyjoin` package.

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(df1, df2,
         by = c('Latitude' = 'Latitude1', 'Latitude' = 'Latitude2', 
                'Longitude' = 'Longitude1', 'Longitude' = 'Longitude2'), 
         match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`, `>=`, `<=`))

#  Latitude Longitude  ID Latitude1 Latitude2 Longitude1 Longitude2
#1     12.1       4.1 ABC     11.50     12.15       3.90       4.15
#2     12.2       4.2 DEF     12.17     12.25       4.17       4.25
```

Comment: Hi brother @Ronak Shah ,

I tried this code and I received an error like this:

> fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(test_longlat, test_grid, 
+                            by = c('LAT_' = 'lat1', 'LAT_' = 'lat2', 
+                                   'LONG_' = 'long1', 'LONG_' = 'long2'), 
+                            match_fun = list("<=", ">=", ">=", "<="))
Error in which(m) : argument to 'which' is not logical

Comment: Why do you have `+` in the code there? Can you remove it and try this? If it doesn't work can you please add data using `dput` so that I can test it at my end? Read on how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Hi Sorry, I just copied the output in the console hence the +

Comment: `code`
df1 <- data.frame(
    Latitude = c(12.10,12.20,12.30),
    Longitude = c(4.10, 4.20, 4.50)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
ID = c('ABC' ,'DEF', 'GHI')    
Latitude1 = c(11.50,12.17,12.27),
Latitude2 = c(12.15,12.25,12.45),
Longitude1 = c(3.90,4.17,4.45),
Longitude2 = c(4.15, 4.25, 4.48)
)

`code`

@Ronak Shah

Comment: @MarcAtanante See updated answer. Works for me on the data you shared.

Comment: Hi buddy, I tried also on the sample dataset and it worked. I tried running the code on the actual dataset but I get a memory error. (df1 = 2.7million rows, df2 = 43k rows)

Comment: This worked but consumes too many resources. I cannot finish the run when I use this code. Nonetheless, this was very helpful so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who helped. I tried a different approach using "SQLDF" and it worked perfectly. Take note that I'm comparing a 2.4 million row dataframe with a 43,000 row lookup dataframe so it took me 3 hours to run.

```
sql_way_test <- function(data,lookup){
  data<-sqldf("select A.*,B.ID from
              data A left join lookup B 
              ON ((A.Latitude >= B.Latitude1 and A.Latitude < B.Latitude2) and
              (A.Longitude >= B.Longitude1 and A.Longitude < B.Longitude2))")
  data
}

df_SQLway <- sql_way_test(data = df1, df2)
```